# Duplicate meta descriptions on dynamically generated page

Tags: seo, prestashop, google-search-console

I have a an e-commerce site. When I see in webmaster tool, it shows several pages has duplicate meta description.

**Problem Statement** : When I click a category say toys, based on the number of toys fetched, total product is shown in various dynamically generated pages. The page URL remains same but on click next button page number is appended in the URL like .http://www.example.com to http://www.example.com/page-2. So overall these are the same page but generated dynamically on the basis of total number of product available.

**Concern** how to make google understand that these are basically same page, so as not to throw duplicate meta description error.

Also, even if these error persists, does it hamper the SEO of my website?

**PS:** the ecommerce is built up on prestashop framewrok, and overall 301 redirect option is activated

Thanks in advance

Comment: But for example, pages example.com/toys and example.com/toys/page-2 present **exactly** the same data or only parts of a bigger list of products ?

Answer (score 2):

Use canonical to prevent duplicity issue. Please rel=canonical tag on all pages.

Comment: thanks.. but can you please elaborate as how to use this rel=canonical. For example, if I use canonical in this way "<link rel="canonical" href=" I am not sure which URL to give in href as my URL is dynamically generated">" . Thanks in advance.. Need urgent solution

Comment: If http://www.example.com/toys is the main page and http://www.example.com/toys/page-2 a simple copy, then put `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/toys" />`.

Did you try to find solutions integrated in Prestashop to implement this ?

Comment: Thanks Michel.I have tried the solution integrated with prestashop. Prestashop gives an option of activating canonical link, and I have selected the option yes,"but it does not work". Also in my ecommerce site we have the basic page as www.example.com and category and its meta description is fetched dynamically based on the category which is selected. eg.  http://www.example.com/14/toys where 14 is the category id and toy is the category name. Now based on the amount of product, the URL is further changed as http://www.example.com/14/toys#/page-2 and so on. Hope I hav stated my problm clearly.

Comment: I was thinking if I can write a regex to replace #page-2 with blank space, so that my URL remains same as example.com/14/toys. Is this feasible, if yes help me out. Any solution is highly appreciated, as I am in deep trouble with this. Thanks

Comment: As said, choose most descriptive page for every product and use url of that in canonical tag.